# change wpf tool tip depends upon current thread culture info

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, tooltip

i am working on WPF application in that i'm able to localize labels buttons but im not able to localize tool tips. It is always coming in english. I changed the cultureinfo to Japanese. But still tooltip alone coming in English rest all are coming in Japanese. How can i control tool tip language

Comment: Could you share some code? or what have you tried?

Comment: <Button.ToolTip>
 <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{x:Static p:Resources.TOOLTIP_UPDT}"></TextBlock>
</Button.ToolTip>
                                    
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button.ToolTip>